# what is tcgetpgrp() return value meaning?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

### Question

man page for tcgetpgrp said

> When fd refers to the controlling terminal of the calling process, the function tcgetpgrp() will return the foreground process group ID of that terminal if there is one, and
>          some value larger than 1 that is not presently a process group ID otherwise.

1. what is the meaning of `some value`, it seems to be ambiguous
2. how can i check it to be a valid group id or a other value, does it mean that I have to get the list of all the process groups in the system to figure out if the return value refers to a valid process group?

### Context

when i try to use it and i find it seems to return current session id
i have tried many times and it always return current session id

[image]

is `some value` mean current session id ? or it is a especial case? or my code has bug?

### env and code

env: libc 2.1.2,  Linux 2.6.32

code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    return getgroup(argc, argv);
}

int getgroup(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (fork()) {
        return OK;
    }
    sleep(5);
    printf("process %d fork, ppid %d, pgid %d, psid %d \n", getpid(), getppid(), getpgid(getpid()), getsid(getpid()));
    pid_t gid = tcgetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO);
    printf("group id %d \n", gid);
    return OK;
}
```

Comment: manual says "The session ID of a process is the process group ID of the session leader." It is telling you that the terminal's process group is the session leader process group. I.e., a session id is always also a valid process group id.

Comment: Your code sample isn't complete (where is `main`?) and it's not clear how you're running it (why does the output appear after a shell prompt?). The latter in particular could affect the output.

Comment: reasonable, when father process exit, there is no foreground process, and terminal control return to shell, is it possible that it return the pgid of bash process ? @Ben

Comment: _some value larger than 1 that is not presently a process group ID_ indicates a number larger than one (a possible valid process group id) but not a process group id, because the system has no process group with that id.  This is the unambiguous meaning of the apparently ambiguous sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing only on the question title of *what is tcgetpgrp() return value meaning?*  that is the process group id that is in control of the terminal that your request the number to.

To explain a little the way things happen so, it is necessary to know how the system handles pids and process group ids, and how the terminal needs to know which process group is in control of that terminal.

When a user logs in, the login shell, interactive and becoming a process group leader, makes the user terminal to know that the process group is the login shell.

For job control, for each pipeline the shell builds and executes, just after forking the first process, it becomes a process group leader (by means of a cal to setpgrp()) and spawns all the commands in the pipeline under that process group.  Then, it makes that processgroup id the process group in control of the terminal and the terminal knows which process group is the controlling process group for that terminal.

This means two things:

- The terminal only can deal with one process group at a time.  Other process groups that have it as controlling terminal are not linked to it (in the sense that they do have a pointer that points to the tty, but as the tty doesn't point to that process group, `read(2)`ing for these processes is not possible).  They will be able to `read(2)` again, once they become again the foreground group (by making the `tty` point to that process group, via the `tcsetpgrp` termios call)
- The shell does this **only** for interactive jobs.  Changing the interactive job means setting the process group to the group of processes that are going to go foreground.  The it has to change the wait, to wait for the process leader of that group.  This excludes all jobs spawned in background (or converted in background jobs with the commands `bg` or `fg`) as the tty now points to a different group of processes. The shell maintains only one foreground process group and many background processes, with Input being possible only for the foreground process group.

The terminal needs to know which process group it is linked to by two reasons:

- The sending of signals `SIGINT`(`Ctrl-C`), `SIGHUP`(`Ctrl-D`) and `SIGQUIT`(`Ctrl-]`) and `SIGSTOP`(`Ctrl-X`) has to be sent to the process group in foreground, so it is sent to the controlling process group.  The signal `SIGHUP` is sent to a broader group of processes, the session group.
- The `tty` read function needs to know if the process reading the terminal is in the process group it points to, so it checks that the process doing the read call has a processgroup id identical to the process group stored in the terminal driver structure.  In case it doesn't match, an error is returned (with errno equals `ENOTTY`)

On other side, becoming a process group leader (the only way of creating a process group) creates a process group with the id equal to the pid of the process issuing the call, so the process group leader has the same number for its pid and the process group id.

Once said this... a control process group id doesn't need to be updated in the terminal.  The terminal should have to be searched when a process `exit(2)`s and it should be tedious to search the complete list of tty devices to delete any control terminal id that can remain there.

But when a process group leader opens a tty, the process group of that tty is changed to the process group of that leader..... so there's no need to navigate all the terminals in the system when a process dies, just to make their control process group id an invalid one.

As you have been told in the answer from @davmac, there are alternate ways of knowing if the number returned is a valid process group id or not, just send a `0` signal (which is there to make it possible to know if a process ---or process group--- exists, and you'll get it).

Of course, in regard of the race condition pointed to by @davmac, take into account the possibility of reusing a pid, but as the kernel manages pids in a least recently used (or near it) manner, very high load is necessary to have such a pid clash.

The reason you always get the process group id of the curren process is that you always launch the program interactively.  Try to launch it in background and you'll see a process group that does not match the process group of the requesting process (it will be the process group of the shell most probably)

Comment: "But when a process group leader opens a tty, the process group of that tty is changed to the process group of that leader" - this is not correct, a process group leader opening a tty does not automatically set the foreground process group of the tty to that process group. That must be done using `tcsetpgrp` or equivalent.

Comment: Have you tested, because it is ancient use, and I have not done that recently.  But in UNIX, when you open a tty, and the tty has no process group attached (which is difficult to achieve) and the process is a process group leader (which means its pgid matches its pid), and the process has not open another tty, then that tty has set it's process group to the process group of the calling process.  I tested this a long time ago (when there was no tcsetpgrp call) and it worked.

Comment: From the man page of the `tcsetpgrp(3)` library call: _...The terminal device associated with fd must be (already) the controlling terminal of the calling process_  quote in parenthesis is mine.  This means that tcsetpgrp(3) call **is not used** to set a terminal as the process group control terminal.  (continue digging in the doc... )

Comment: very funny, i am beginning to understand why terminal only has one foreground process group ;  i'm learning about unix process, and i read 《work with unix process》,it is simple and clear, but seems not give a deeper explanation in many chapter. i was troubled by process group and session for a long time, and i found many with google, most of article only tell what is this and how to use  but no why use this way,  can you recommend some book about unix process or unix operate system?

Comment: @LuisColorado I have tested it, yes (on Linux). For the behaviour you describe the process would need to have no controlling terminal before it opened the terminal. That requirement, and the requirement that the terminal does not already have an associated process group, are not mentioned in your answer. _"This means that tcsetpgrp(3) call is not used to set a terminal as the process group control terminal"_ - that's right, it's used to set the foreground process group of the terminal.

Comment: @LuisColorado there's another things wrong in your answer too: _"The terminal only can deal with one process group. Other process groups are not linked with that terminal"_ - not correct; any number of process groups can have the terminal as their controlling terminal, but only one can be the foreground process group at any one time.

Comment: @lilin the GNU C library manual has quite good information (though not always 100% clear): https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html

Comment: @davmac, i've not said the opposite, many groups can have the same tty as control terminal.  a process cannot have several control terminals, and a termina can only have a control process group.  What I have said, is that, to be able to read from a tty, the pointers from process to terminal and from terminal to process group must point to each other.  The sentence _Other process groups are not linked with that terminal_ is bad typo.  I meant what I say above.  The terminal always sends the keyborard signals to the process group (except `SIGHUP` which is sent to process session group)

Comment: process groups were invented to manage job control... and process group sessions to manage sessions on interactive login sessions or daemon process groups.

Answer (score 6):

> 1. what is the meaning of some value, it seems to be ambiguous

It means what it says, I think: some (arbitrary) value that is not a process group id. (Most likely what it actually returns is the process group ID that was the foreground group, before it terminated; this is unlikely to be visible in practice, since the shell will usually set another process as the foreground process immediately when its child which was previously in the foreground terminates).

> 2. how can i check it to be a valid group id or a other value, does it mean that I have to get the list of all the process groups in the system to figure out if the return value refers to a valid process group?

You can use `kill` with a negative argument to signal a process group (the process group signalled will be the absolute value of the argument), and use a signal number of 0. This will return -1 with errno set to `ESRCH` if the process group doesn't exist, or do nothing (and return 0) if it does exist.

(It might also be possible to use `killpg`, but the manual page does not document the possibility of using a signal number of 0, so I am not certain).

There is, however, a race condition: the process group may have existed at the time that `tcgetgrp` was called, but terminated since; conversely, it might not have existed, but a new process group with the same ID may have come into existence. This makes it really only useful for checking process groups that the current process controls (i.e. for which it can prevent reaping) - specifically, groups which are lead by child processes of the current process (or which are lead by the current process itself).

If that seems limiting, consider: in what situations do you actually need to know which process group is in the foreground, and why?

Comment: thanks,I have gained so much. you are right, it is not necessary to know which process group is in the foreground, i use it because i learn process and see this system call, and i don't understand what's the meaning of `some value`, so i give it a try.   

by the way,  how to explain the result of picture, i think it maybe pgid of bash process :  when father process exit, there is no foreground process, and terminal control return to shell, is it possible that it return the pgid of bash process ?

Comment: i have another question, when we execute a programe, it fork a child process and it is foreground process group,   when father process exit, child process hosted by init process and it is still keep process group,  is child's process group foreground or background?

Comment: @lilin I think you'll find that the shell makes its own process group the foreground process group once a process you run via it returns. In answer to your second question, this doesn't happen automatically - the shell (or another program) must do it; until then, the process group of your program is the foreground group.

Comment: @davmac, the system checks that a process group doesn't exist before creating a valid process group... It uses the allocation of pids, as the only way to create a process group is to become a processgroup leader (by definition pgrpid `==` process group lider pid)

Comment: @LuisColorado I know that. I don't understand what point you are making?

Comment: @davmac, my comment was on your explanation of the race condition of a terminal that sees how it's controlling group dies, and the same id is reallocated again after some time... read my answer, that complements yours.

Comment: @LuisColorado <strike>are you saying that if a process group is the foreground group of some terminal, and all processes within it terminate (thus the process group itself terminates), that no other process group with the same ID will be created until another process group becomes the foreground process for the terminal? Interesting. Do you have a source for the information?</strike> Ah never mind. I understand now. You are saying it is unlikely that the PID will be re-used. I agree, but if security is at stake, it's best to consider.

Comment: nope.... processroup ids are created from living pids only... and pids are not reallocated until all processes in a process group have `exit()`ed.  So no chance to see the same process group id in short time (in the same time order as the reallocation of the same pid by the kernel)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176423/discussion-between-luis-colorado-and-davmac).